# How to copy structured data allocated in device memory from device to host

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm new to GPU and CUDA programming. I am trying to copy structured data dynamically allocated on device from device to host. I modified a simple code from GPU programming guide. I don't get any error when compiling the code but the only thing I have that's problematic is the output is wrong i.e. '0'. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Point
{
    int2 pt;
};

#define NUMOFBLOCKS 1
#define THREDSPERBLOCK  16

__device__ Point* pnt[NUMOFBLOCKS];
Point dataptr_h[NUMOFBLOCKS][THREDSPERBLOCK];

__global__ void allocmem() 
{   
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)       
        pnt[blockIdx.x] = (Point*)malloc(1*blockDim.x * sizeof(Point)); 
    __syncthreads(); 
} 

__global__ void usemem() 
{ 
    Point* ptr = pnt[blockIdx.x]; 
    if (ptr != NULL) 
    {       
        ptr[threadIdx.x].pt.x = threadIdx.x; 
        ptr[threadIdx.x].pt.y = threadIdx.x;
        printf("Ptr = %d\t", ptr[threadIdx.x].pt.x);
    }
}

__global__ void freemem() 
{ 
    Point* ptr = pnt[blockIdx.x]; 
    if (ptr != NULL) 
        printf("Block %d, Thread %d: final value = %d\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, ptr[threadIdx.x]); 
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) 
        free(ptr); 
}


int main()
{
    Point* d_pt[NUMOFBLOCKS];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMOFBLOCKS; i++)
        cudaMalloc(&d_pt[i], sizeof(Point)*16);  

    // Allocate memory  
    allocmem<<< NUMOFBLOCKS, THREDSPERBLOCK >>>();  
    // Use memory 
    usemem<<< NUMOFBLOCKS, THREDSPERBLOCK >>>(); 
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(d_pt, pnt, sizeof(d_pt));
    cudaMemcpy(dataptr_h, d_pt, sizeof(dataptr_h), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < 1; j++)
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
        {
            printf("\nPtr_h(%d,%d)->X = %d\t", j, i, dataptr_h[j][i].pt.x);
            printf("Ptr_h(%d,%d)->Y = %d", j, i, dataptr_h[j][i].pt.y);
        }

    freemem<<< NUMOFBLOCKS, THREDSPERBLOCK >>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
Ptr_h(0,0)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,0)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,1)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,1)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,2)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,2)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,3)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,3)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,4)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,4)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,5)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,5)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,6)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,6)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,7)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,7)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,8)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,8)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,9)->X = 0       Ptr_h(0,9)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,10)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,10)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,11)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,11)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,12)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,12)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,13)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,13)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,14)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,14)->Y = 0
Ptr_h(0,15)->X = 0      Ptr_h(0,15)->Y = 0
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should do proper [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all CUDA API calls and kernel calls.  It will point out the lines of code you are having trouble with.  Since your kernel printf statements don't show up, it's reasonably clear that your kernels are not executing properly. Running your code with `cuda-memcheck` will likely shed light on that.

Comment: In fact, when I run your code, some of your kernel printf statements do show up.  So if you're not seeing `Ptr = 0 Ptr = 1 ...` then you may have another issue (machine configuration) as well.  But proper cuda error checking will help you discover if that is the case also.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your comment. But printf works well in kernel and I can see Ptr = 0 Ptr = 1 ... The only problem is that this data is not passed / copied to host. I'm trying to follow your next answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a pointer created by a device `malloc` operation with the CUDA runtime API (i.e. `cudaMemcpy`)

So this line of code is problematic:

```
cudaMemcpy(dataptr_h, d_pt, sizeof(dataptr_h), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

`d_pt` contains pointers picked up from `pnt`.  And `pnt` had it's value(s) set by device `malloc`.

Instead you'll need to create areas properly allocated with `cudaMalloc`, then copy the data you want to those areas first (from one area on the device to another area), then copy to the host using `cudaMemcpy`.

Before I go farther to explain your next objection, let's be clear that the above is your intent (to use a pointer created in a device `malloc` operation as one of the targets of a `cudaMemcpy`).  This is not legal.

"But I *used* `cudaMalloc` ??"

`d_pt` is an array of pointers that live in host memory.  You took each one of those pointers and assigned it a value (a pointed-to location in device memory) using `cudaMalloc`.

Then this line of code:

```
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(d_pt, pnt, sizeof(d_pt));
```

*over-wrote* all those pointers that you set up with pointers obtained from elsewhere in device memory, specifically pointers assigned by device `malloc`.  While this is technically legal (that line of code does not throw an error) those pointers are *useless* on the host (for use with the runtime API, anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What is the alternate way, if we cannot use a pointer created by a device <malloc> operation with the CUDA runtime API (<cudaMemcpy>)? What does <cudaMemcpyFromSymbol> do then? I mean what is the purpose of that function if it doesn't pass the pointer allocated in the device?

Comment: The alternate way is to allocate memory areas using `cudaMalloc` and use those instead of device-allocated areas.  I already indicated this in my response.  `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` copies data from a `__device__` area/variable to the host.  It serves a pupose similar to `cudaMemcpy`

Comment: I tried to allocate memory using `cuaMalloc` but could not get thru... Moreover, I read in the CUDA programming guide 4.2 that Memory allocated via `malloc()` can be copied using the runtime (i.e. by calling any of the copy memory functions). Please refer to the `section B.17.2 of CUDA C Programming Guide 4.2`.

Comment: So, I'm a bit confused now. My understanding (I could be wrong) is that mem copy should work using `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` if we copy from device i.e. symbol `pnt` to host `dataptr_h`,  as explained by you too that `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` copies data from a `__device__` area to the host. But it's not working here.

Comment: So you've referenced the CUDA 4.2 programming guide.  Are you using CUDA 4.2?

Comment: I've CUDA 4.1, 4.2 and 5.0, but the data copy works on none of those. Although I couldn't find this reference in CUDA 5 programming guide, yet it dosen't work on either of the versions.

Comment: My claim, as I've stated already in my answer, is that using a device pointer created with `malloc` does not work with the host APIs.  The statement you found in the CUDA 4.2 documentation is not present in the current documentation, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've done some experiments and found that it doesn't work...but that's weird... Anyway, thank you for your help.